# C#: Creating a generic extension method with a type parameter for a generic class without specifying the class type parameter

Tags: c#, generics, extension-methods

I would like to have a generic immutable data class with a list of extensions, which can be accessed using extension methods. I can do this with the following code:

```
public class GenericData<T> where T : unmanaged
{
    public GenericData(T data, IList<IDataExtension> extensions)
    {
        Data = data;
        Extensions = extensions.ToImmutableList();
    }

    public T Data { get; }

    public IImmutableList<IDataExtension> Extensions { get; }
}

public interface IDataExtension { }

public static class GenericDataExtensions
{
    public static TExtension GetExtension<TExtension, TDataType>(this GenericData<TDataType> data)
        where TExtension : IDataExtension
        where TDataType : unmanaged
    {
        return data.Extensions.OfType<TExtension>().First();
    }
}
```

This works fine, but requires me to pass in `TDataType` every time I want to get an extension, even though the data type isn't needed for the extension method implementation.

```
public interface IEvenlySpacedXAxisExtension : IDataExtension
{
    EvenlySpacedXAxisInfo Info { get; }
}

// later...

var xAxisInfo = data.GetExtension<IEvenlySpacedXAxisExtension, float>().Info;
```

I could solve this by putting `GetExtension()` behind an interface and making `GenericData` implement it:

```
public class GenericData<T> : IHaveDataExtensions where T : unmanaged
{
    public GenericData(T data, IList<IDataExtension> extensions)
    {
        Data = data;
        Extensions = extensions.ToImmutableList();
    }

    public T Data { get; }

    public IImmutableList<IDataExtension> Extensions { get; }
}

public interface IDataExtension { }

public interface IHaveDataExtensions
{
    IImmutableList<IDataExtension> Extensions { get; }
}

public static class IHaveExtensionsExtensions
{
    public static TExtension GetExtension<TExtension>(this IHaveDataExtensions objectWithExtensions)
        where TExtension : IDataExtension
    {
        return objectWithExtensions.Extensions.OfType<TExtension>().First();
    }
}
```

This works, but requires an unnecessary layer of abstraction and looks pretty messy. Is there a cleaner way to achieve the same result?

Comment: In your first approach, you created the extension method for a generic class, so when you access its extension method, you have to pass both TData and TExtension.

2nd approach, you created the extension for an Interface where you required only TExtension to access data because you created the wrapper layer for IExtensions.

your 2nd approach is correct and that's how we can implement the extension method for a generic interface.

I'm not sure why you need an extension method here, because if you create `GetExtention<IExtension>()` directly inside the `GData` it will be cleaner!

Answer (score 0):

My use case was similar and what worked for me is writing an extension *for* type T. The extension class also has a static property to hold the "immutable list of extensions".

```
public static class GenericDataExtensions
{
    public static TExtension GetExtension<T>(this T any)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Requesting extension for type '{any.GetType().Name}'");
        if(ImmutableListOfExtensions.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out TExtension tExtension))
        {
            return tExtension;
        }
        return default(TExtension); // To do: Handle case of 'not found'.
    }
    internal static IReadOnlyDictionary<Type, TExtension> 
}
```

The mock of the TExtension class goes like so:

```
public class TExtension
{
    public TExtension(string name) => Name = name;
    public string Name { get; }
}
```

And here is a simple test driver that initializes the dictionary and retrieves an extension:

```
[TestMethod]
public void InferredExtensionGetterTest()
{
    // Initialize the static extension class
    var initializer = new Dictionary<Type, TExtension>
    {
        {typeof(A), new TExtension("Extension for class A") },
        {typeof(B), new TExtension("Extension for class B") },
        {typeof(C), new TExtension("Extension for class C") },
    };
    GenericDataExtensions.ImmutableListOfExtensions = initializer;

    var classA = new A();
    var classB = new B();
    var classC = new C();

    TExtension extension;
    extension = classA.GetExtension();
    Console.WriteLine($"Retrieved: {extension.Name}{Environment.NewLine}");

    extension = classB.GetExtension();
    Console.WriteLine($"Retrieved: {extension.Name}{Environment.NewLine}");

    extension = classC.GetExtension();
    Console.WriteLine($"Retrieved: {extension.Name}{Environment.NewLine}");
}
```

[image]